# Jquery calculation returns NaN when it should return an int

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm making a calculation in which I add up the values of all text inputs and get a total that I set as the value of another text input. I think this code should work for that, but it returns NaN. What am I doing wrong?

```
var sum = 0;
        $('.price').each(function() {
            amt = parseFloat($(this).val());
            sum += Number(amt);
        });
      console.log(sum);
      $("#order-total").val("€" + sum);
```

Comment: Probably, one of the .price fields is empty.

Comment: no problem here..html code please!

Comment: `console.log($(this).val(), amt, sum)` in the .each and it should be obvious whats up ...

Comment: html is added. .price fields default value is 0. So that shouldn't be the problem, right?

Comment: parseFloat("€0") is NaN

Comment: &euro in value? I mean what is it?

Comment: Remove `&euro;` before attempting conversion

Comment: value `&euro;0` should be `0` or need to filter numeric values before `parseInt`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use zero if the value is not a number, and remove anything that could cause an error

```
var sum = 0;
$('.price').each(function() {
 amt  = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, '').replace(',','.')) || 0;
 sum += amt;
});
$("#order-total").val("€" + sum);
```

Comment: Ideally, an invalid input should be flagged or prevented in the first place using validation, so that there can be no confusion.  Replacing non-numeric characters could be a problem if someone in Germany types `1,50` (where parseFloat would expect 1.50), your code would interpret that as `150` after replacing the `,`.

Comment: @AndyE - if that's really an issue, it's really easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Remove € sign before convert it to float and check that result is a number before to sum it:

```
var sum = 0;
    $('.price').each(function() {
         // val() will return something like "€45.6";
        amt = parseFloat($(this).val().substring(1)));
        sum += isNaN(amt) ? 0 : amt;
    });
  console.log(sum);
  $("#order-total").val("€" + sum);
```

Comment: .val would return the char not the entity;

Answer (score 1):

well you have written &euro in the value field I guess it is creating problem

```
<td><input type="text" class="price" value="&euro;0"></td>
```

put this instead of above code

```
<td><input type="text" class="price" value="0"></td>
```

put below code to put validation

```
sum += isNaN(amt) ? 0 : amt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the 1st character to see if its a euro symbol and if so, remove it.

You need to look for the *character* not the *entity*:

```
    $('.price').each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.charAt(0) === '\u20AC')
            value = value.substr(1);

        sum += parseFloat(value);
    });
```